Angular no se autorefresca al ingresar un dato
tengo un detalle, cuando listo las personas funciona bien, pero cuando le doy ingresar una persona se envia a la base de datos (Firebase realtime), pero no me aparece en la lista de personas ese registro que acabo de ingresar, debo refrescar la pagina para que funcione, y si ingreso dos seguidos sin refrescar la pagino el primero que ingrese no se guarda, ya revise y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, agradeceria su ayuda.
data.service.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonasModels } from './personas/personas.models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  cargarDatos(): Observable<PersonasModels[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<PersonasModels[]>('https://angular-f7eae-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Datos.json');
  }

  enviarDatos(personas: PersonasModels[]) {
    this.httpClient.put('https://angular-f7eae-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Datos.json', personas)
    .subscribe({
      next: Response => console.log("Todo correcto " + Response),
      error: Error => console.log("Error " + Error)
    });
  }

}

personas.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { PersonasModels } from './personas.models';

@Injectable()
export class PersonasService {

  constructor(private dataServices: DataService) { }

  lista_personas: PersonasModels[] = [];

  agregarPersona(persona: PersonasModels) {
    if (this.lista_personas == null) {
      this.lista_personas = [];
    }
    this.lista_personas.push(persona);
    this.dataServices.enviarDatos(this.lista_personas);
  }

  obtenerDatos() {
    return this.dataServices.cargarDatos();
  }

}

listapersonas.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonasModels } from '../personas/personas.models';
import { PersonasService } from '../personas/personas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listarpersonas',
  templateUrl: './listarpersonas.component.html',
  styleUrl: './listarpersonas.component.css'
})
export class ListarpersonasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private personasServices: PersonasService) { }

  lista_personas: PersonasModels[] = []
  ngOnInit() {
    this.personasServices.obtenerDatos()
    .subscribe({
      next: (lista_personas: PersonasModels[]) => {
          this.personasServices.lista_personas = lista_personas;
          this.lista_personas = this.personasServices.lista_personas;
          console.log(lista_personas);
        }
    })
  }
}

personas.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonasService } from './personas.service';
import { PersonasModels } from './personas.models';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personas',
  templateUrl: './personas.component.html',
  styleUrl: './personas.component.css'
})
export class PersonasComponent {

  constructor(private personasServices: PersonasService, private router: Router) { }

  nombre: String = "";
  apellido: String = "";

  agregarPersona() {
    this.personasServices.agregarPersona(new PersonasModels(this.nombre, this.apellido));
    this.nombre = "";
    this.apellido = "";
    this.router.navigate(['ListarPersonas']);
  }

}


No es un detalle, es un error de implementación o diseño. En ningún momento indicas que se actualice el componente, haciendo una petición GET después de agregar un elemento debería ser suficiente. También tienes la alternativa de agregarlo al arreglo y no hacer doble petición (crear y obtener).
agregarPersona() {
  this.personasServices.agregarPersona(new PersonasModels(this.nombre, this.apellido));
  this.personasServices.obtenerDatos().subscribe({
    next: (lista_personas: PersonasModels[]) => {
      this.personasServices.lista_personas = lista_personas;
    }
  });
}

Como extra:

Estas dos líneas son redundantes:

this.personasServices.lista_personas = lista_personas;
this.lista_personas = this.personasServices.lista_personas;

al menos que por alguna razón necesites mantener una copia.

Reutiliza el manejo de errores:

private errorHandler(error: any) : void {
 console.error("Ocurrió un error: ", error);
}

queda así:
catchError(this.manejarError) 

ó
error: this.manejarError

